# Green Arrow over class icon (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio

What is the green right arrow over the class icon in the project navigator sidebar in android studio indicate? What does the red left arrow indicate? I'm new to the IDE and just want to get a better understanding.

[image]

[image]

Comment: JUnit tests always show the red and green arrow over the class icon.  I have never noticed the single green arrow over a class icon.  Take a look at the type of class it is and that should give you a hint.  For example different icons are supplied for abstract classes, interfaces... I was unable to track down any Android documentation to list all icons and their meanings, hopefully someone can find this and provide a link as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a link to the all the icons and there meaning on the ItelliJ site:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html

The green arrow denotes a Java class that contains declaration of the main() method.

The green and red arrow denote a test case.